# __AVX2__ appears not to be defined in eclipse-cdt

Tags: gcc, g++, eclipse-cdt, intrinsics, avx2

My compiler supports avx2, and I added `-mavx2` to C++ flags, but
the `__AVX2__` macro is not defined in my code.

```
#ifdef __AVX2__
#include <immintrin.h>
#endif
```

appears to be disabled in the code.

Edit:

My complier version is:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: `-mavx2` should work with gcc-4.7 or later: https://godbolt.org/z/aEZQez Are you using that or `-march=native`? In the latter case, are you sure your CPU supports AVX2?

Comment: Thanks, I am using `-mavx2`.  And yes, doing `cat /proc/cpuinfo` shows avx2 supported. Sadly, I have to manually check cpuinfo and then define these macros.

Comment: Can you show the output of `gcc --version` (or `g++ --version`)?

Comment: Thanks - updated above.

Comment: What's the complete compiler command line? And how have you determined that `__AVX2__` is not defined?

Comment: @FlorianWeimer I am using cmake to generate the make files and compiler command. I know `__AVX2__` is not defined because my editor Eclipse CDT is greying out the code.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer :) thanks - so, this is just an editor issue! it turns out the __AVX2__ is indeed defined.

Comment: You can put this comment as an answer to the question - purely an editor issue.

Answer (score 1):

To make eclipse aware that AVX2 is available, you can go to the project properties under

```
C/C++ General
    Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc.
        Providers
            CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings
```

and add `-mavx2` or `-march=native` to the "Command to get compiler specs".

Alternatively, you can set this in the global preferences under

```
C/C++
    Build
        Settings
            Discovery
                CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings
```

N.B. while you are at that setting, you can also add things like `-std=c++17` (or whatever standard you usually use).

Comment: Thanks!  I added ${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}"  "-mavx2"  in Discovery but it didn't change anything unfortunately

Comment: Also, I didn't see an entry for `CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings` under project settings

Comment: Leave out the `"` around `-mavx2`. And perhaps try it in front of `"${INPUTS}"`. You may need to re-index your project (try this with a small test-project first).

Comment: Thanks, removed the quotes, moved it in front, and re-indexed - still greyed out :(